# Visual Studio full screen applications with C#

Tags: c#, fullscreen, stretch

I want to make an applications that works like Word, Excel, Power Point etc... I mean if you maximize or change the window size to something different the program will always adjust the inside elements in a very nice way.

I'm creating a new "WindowsFormsApplication" in Visual Studio 2012 with C#

Thanx !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://avalondock.codeplex.com/, it provides a Visual Studio style interface out of the box, and is very extensible.

Last time I checked it didn't support MVVM so well, but that might not be such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic resizing in WinForms is very easy, and most (if not all) of the behavior you want can likely be achieved simply by choosing the right controls and property settings.

To get started in the right direction, read up on the following topics:

- [Control.Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)
- [Control.Dock Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx)
- [TableLayoutPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)
- [FlowLayoutPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx)

It is easy enough to create a quick test app and drop some controls on it to see how they behave.  No coding required.